# Get an element in random from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I efficiently select an element at random from an RDD of string?

Comment: I did it in some non sensical way by mapping RDD to zipWithIndex and used Random.shuffle with the count and picked the index

Comment: [`takeSample`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use `takeSample`. Example :

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Range(1,100))
// data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[9] at parallelize at <console>:27

data.takeSample(false,1)
// res9: Array[Int] = Array(38)

data.takeSample(false,1)
// res10: Array[Int] = Array(72)

data.takeSample(false,1)
// res11: Array[Int] = Array(93)
```

In case you wanted to fetch the same "random" element you can fix the seed :

```
data.takeSample(false, 1, seed = 10L)
// res14: Array[Int] = Array(62)

data.takeSample(false, 1, seed = 10L)
// res15: Array[Int] = Array(62)
```

Comment: can we have seed as System.nanoTime.toInt?

Comment: You can use any seed you like. However the seed is a long, so really you should give it one of them. I'm not sure why @eliasah uses a random seed as that is what it [defaults](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) too.

Comment: That's true @mlk I wasn't sure as I wrote the code on the fly.